# Fragment back button press , and pressing button twice to close app

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have fragments [0], [1], [2], [3], [4] and [5].

I would like to implement the back button on each fragment to return to the main fragment. While in the main fragment I would like to be able to press the back button twice before exiting the program.

As of now pressing back twice works, but it works on all fragments. When pressing back on any of the fragments the app closes it does not go back to the main fragment. 
 I want that function only to work on the main fragment.

Here is my code which is on my main fragment activity.

```
private static long back_pressed; 
private Toast toast;
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{ 


    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
        {

             // need to cancel the toast here
         toast.cancel();  

         // code for exit
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
        else 
        {
        // ask user to press back button one more time to close app 
        toast=  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.show();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try on this way:

Create public variable int counter = 0, and inside onBackPressed put counter++. After that put if(counter==2){ ....}

```
    public int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    { 
        counter++;
        if(counter == 2){
        do something....}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether the currently visible fragment is your main fragment. To do this

```
final MyFragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myFragmentTag);
if (fragment.isVisible()) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```